# Advanced Sheets Service API and google script fail when copying large amounts of cells formulas into values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

## Issue

Currently I have a spreadsheet with over 25,000 rows and growing. In order to lighten the spreadsheet and improve speeds I thought of having a script to remove formulas and paste their values. If in Col `I:I` the value is "Removed" then replace all formulas from `J:X` with values.

The original working script was

```
function removed() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9, sheet.getLastRow(), 16);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, 15).setValues(values);
}
```

However, this stopped at around row 6000 after which it produced the error (100-200 seconds)

> Nov 3, 2022, 3:23:12 PM Error   Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id xxx
> at removed(Remove Formula:6:41)

### First fix attempt

After I edited `getRange(1, 9, sheet.getLastRow(), 16);` to A1 notation `I:X`, it improved significantly, the script would succesfully work its way all the way to row 12,000 (~250s).

```
function removed() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:X");
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

### Second fix attempt

I also tried splitting the rows. With `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` where the error usually comes, as suggested in other posts. Neither splitting into different batches nor flushing had any positive impact.

```
function onOpen() {
   var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Remove Formulas");
   menu.addItem("Remove formulas Script", "settingA");
   menu.addToUi();
}


function settingA() {
    removed1();
    removed2();
    removed2();
}

function removed1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:X10000");
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
}

function removed2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range2 = sheet.getRange("I10001:X20000");
  var formulas2 = range2.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values2 = range2.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas2[i]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range2.offset(0, 1, values2.length, values2[0].length).setValues(values2);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}

function removed3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range3 = sheet.getRange("I20001:X");
  var formulas3 = range3.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values3 = range3.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas3[i]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range3.offset(0, 1, values3.length, values3[0].length).setValues(values3);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
```

### Third fix attempt (API)

@TheMaster pointed out Advanced Sheets Service API is a solution to this type of error.
Given my lack of knowledge, I tried it last. However, once I got it working (100-5000 rows) without errors, I attempted to implement it in the full 25k row sheet and it failed in a very similar fashion, only difference was the error type. However it stops around 6000-8000 and lasts 50s longer than without API (~200s) before error.

> Nov 4, 2022, 1:34:37 PM    Error   GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: The service is currently unavailable.
> at removed(Untitled:17:30)

```
function removed() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:X");
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  var range2 = range.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length);  
  var request = {
    'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [
      {
        'range': 'test!' + range2.getA1Notation(),
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': values
      }
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```

If anyone has any ideas of why this is failing or what could be done to improve or outright fix it, I would be very grateful.

Also batches could be a solution, but then I am just concerned, for example, about having to come every time an extra 10,000 rows are created.

Comment: 25,000 rows by 16 columns is not too much. The first function you quote looks fine. It is possible that your spreadsheet is running slow because of some issue other than the data and formulas you mention. See [these spreadsheet optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).

Comment: @doubleunary Well, not particularly slow. This current spreadsheet is already a light version of its original self. And those 16 columns are 95-99% of all formulas. So without saying for sure its because of a heavy file, which i doubt, i dont understand why the errors come so early (200-250s) when scripts time out at 6mins.

Comment: @doubleunary And i already follow all of the suggested optimization tips.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try `var range = sheet.getRange(2,9,sheet.getLastRow()-1,11);`

Comment: @TheWizEd I usually used `var range = sheet.getRange(2,9,sheet.getLastRow()-1,16);` when not using A1 notation, but it lasted just as long as `var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9, sheet.getLastRow(), 16);` Although in your comment the last "," is 11. So not sure if you meant that.

Comment: Yes sorry miss counted on my fingers should be 16.

Comment: Try to make a copy of your spreadsheet and try the code in the new one.

Comment: @TheMaster I am currently testing on a duplicate spreadsheet as to not change anything on a live spreadsheet. On both, in the original (in a duplicate sheet) and in a duplicate spreadsheet the scripts behave the same way.

Comment: *Neither splitting into different batches nor flushing had any positive impact.* Ok, but what was the impact? Did it fail in `removed1` or `removed2`? What happens?

Comment: @TheMaster it failed in removed 2 `range2.offset(0, 1, values2.length, values2[0].length).setValues(values2);` it is always this step after around 12k rows. Regarding the links, is there a solution there, or just a reference to a similar issue?

Comment: Linked Apps script tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156530211 Linked sheets api trackers: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191608%2B%20The%20service%20is%20currently%20unavailable

Comment: Reference to similar issues with solutions suggested by some. `it is always this step after around 12k`  Maybe something is in that row? Like data validation preventing setValue process? Try deleting 11k-13k th rows.

Comment: @TheMaster i will check for any weird rows, however, it is a new spreadsheet, and there should only be formulas between `J:X`. I now just double check to remove all possible data validations and will execute again. I don't think it is, after all the time are very similar between all scripts (under 250s). Do you suggest moving to chat discussion? I saw it said it is recommended.

Comment: `after all the time are very similar between all scripts` Maybe That's because it takes that much time to finish the previous rows before reaching that row.

Comment: Sidenote: Before someone asks for a spreadsheet, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster You may be on to something but i have no idea what. So i have two very similar spreadsheets with the same inital 25k list and different formulas J:X on this second one (a copy of to avoid working on live) the API script worked in 216s. I have no idea what it is and i made sure to remove data validation just in case there was one or more hidden around.